# How to sort a filtered array in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I sort the below code to be in order of the name?

```js
const instruments = [
  { 
    id: 0,
    name: 'guitar',
    type: INSTRUMENT_TYPE_STRING
  },
  { 
    id: 1,
    name: 'xylophone',
    type: INSTRUMENT_TYPE_PERCUSSION
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'zither',
    type: INSTRUMENT_TYPE_STRING
  },
```

This is what I've tried but doesn't seem to work.

```js
const sortItems = (objArr) => {
    return
instruments.sort(instrument => instrument.name);
```

Comment: instruments.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1)

Comment: @Nonik or even better `(a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)`

Comment: See [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax). Specifically, look at the parameters for the `compareFunction` and the examples below